# How to append an image to a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have multiple classes with the same tag (.offer) I am going through a loop and it adds the image to all my .offer divs. I just want to add the image specific to the user who posted. How can I do this? Assume the backend is working completely fine

**jQuery** (1st function)

```
    function getOffers(key) {
            dict = {
                'key': key// pk value of post sent to retrieve offers to it
            };

            generateCSRFToken();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/retrieve_offers/",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(dict),
                success: function (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);

                    console.log(appendUserImage(38));
                    $("#offercontainer").empty();
                    $(".offer").empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        var string = data[i].fields.author_name;
                        $("#offercontainer").append(
                            "<div class='offer'>" +
                            "<p class=offername>" + string + "</p>" +
                            "<p class=offertext> offered his " + " " + data[i].fields.item_name +  "</p>" +
                            "</div>"
                        );
                        appendUserImage(data[i].fields.author);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                }

            })
        }
```

**jQuery** (2nd function)

```
  function appendUserImage(key) {
        dict = {
            'key': key// pk value of post sent to retrieve offers to it
        };
        generateCSRFToken();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get_user/",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(dict),
            success: function (data) {
                $('<img />', {
                    src: data["image"],
                    class: "offer_user_image"
                }).appendTo($('.offer'))

            },
            error: function () {
            }

        });

    }
```

I just want to append the image to its respective offer div pls help

Answer (score 0):

you can pass to `appendUserImage` the div `getOffers` function creates  or do something like this, add an unique key selector to the created .offer container and targeting it in the `appendUserImage` function.

in `function getOffers(key) {`

```
$("#offercontainer").append(
  "<div class='offer' data-author-key='" + data[i].fields.author +"'>" +
  "<p class=offername>" + string + "</p>" +
  "<p class=offertext> offered his " + " " + data[i].fields.item_name +  "</p>" +
  "</div>");
  appendUserImage(data[i].fields.author);
```

in `function appendUserImage(key) {`

```
$('<img />', {
 src: data["image"],
 class: "offer_user_image"
 }).appendTo($('.offer[data-author-key="' + key + '"]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the people who tried answering I managed to fix my problem by using nth child and doing this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    var string = data[i].fields.author_name;
                    $("#offercontainer").append(
                        "<div class='offer'>" +
                        "<p class=offername>" + string + "</p>" +
                        "<p class=offertext> offered his " + " " + data[i].fields.item_name +  "</p>" +
                        "</div>"
                    );
                    appendUserImage(i,data[i].fields.author);
                }
```

**2nd function:**

```
function appendUserImage(i,key) {
        dict = {
            'key': key// pk value of post sent to retrieve offers to it
        };
        generateCSRFToken();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get_user/",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(dict),
            success: function (data) {
                $('<img />', {
                    src: data["image"],
                    class: "offer_user_image"
                }).appendTo($('.offer:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')'))

            },
            error: function () {
            }

        });

    }
```